# Maven testCompile works with Java 9 Build 166, but fails with Build 167

Tags: java, maven, junit, java-9

When compiling JUnit tests with **Maven 3.5.0** and **Java 9 build 167**, I get the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project ...: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: -Xmodule:...
```

The reason is: `-Xmodule` has been removed in Java 9 build 167 and later builds.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has already been reported on Maven Issue Tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-294. You can still ask for a workaround there.

As [quickly viewing code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-compiler-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/TestCompilerMojo.java?view=markup#l234), you can add a test module descriptor